# Proof by contradiction algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let n be an integer. Prove that if $n^2+2n-1$ is even, then $n$ is odd.

This is what i have tried so far

If $n$ is even then $n = 2k$
And $n^2+2n-1$ is odd

$$(2k)^2+2(2k)-1 = 4k^2+4k-1$$

Comment: You've proven the statement ("if [big term] is even, $n$ is odd") by contrapositive ("if $n$ is even, [big term] is odd") rather than contradiction ("assume [big term] even and $n$ even, this is absurd"). But that's fine, because the contrapositive is logically equivalent to the original statement. Your proof should have $(2k)^2 = 4k^2$ instead of $4k$ but it's otherwise correct (although you shouldn't be assuming $n^2 + 2n - 1$ is odd, you should be showing it).

Comment: This is really not "abstract algebra".

Comment: I've adjusted the tags.

Answer (score 1):

OK. That's good, although you messed up the algebra when you simplified to $8k-1$. So what you want to say is

1. Suppose $n^2 + 2n - 1$ is even; we want to show $n$ is odd.
2. Well, $n$ is either even or odd.
3. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that it's **even**, i.e., there's an integer $k$ with $n = 2k$.
4. Then $n^2 + 2n - 1 = 4k^2 + 4k - 1$ ... and then some more words to show that this expression is odd.
5. That contradicts statement 0, so the contradiction hypothesis in step 2 must be false.
6. Therefore, by step 1, $n$ must be odd.

Comment: Thanks John for your answer. I am not so clear on proofs so i am trting to figure it all out and make sense of it

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is good, you just need to piece your argument together a bit. Your argument should look more like this:

Suppose $n^2+2n-1$ is even and, in order to reach a contradiction, suppose $n$ is even. Then $n=2k$ and \begin{align*}n^2+2n-1&=(2k)^2+2(2k)-1\\&=4k^2+4k-1\end{align*} Can you show that the right-hand side is odd? If so, do you see how you would have arrived at a contradiction?

Comment: Hi thanks for yoyr answer but one thing i do not understand is proofs

Comment: A proof is just an argument for correctness. What you claimed, in the original post, is that you want a proof by contradiction. To arrive at such a proof, you do the following:

1) Assume the negation (opposite) of the statement you want to prove
2) Show that this leads to a contradiction, i.e., something that is either always false or contradicts the original assumptions of the proof
3) Conclude that negation of the original statement is false, i.e., the statement you want to prove is true

Comment: Okay i got you. Thanks again

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference

Answer (score 1):

If $n^2 + 2n - 1$ is even, then

$(n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n^2 + 2n - 1) + 2 \tag 1$

is also even; now, the square of an even is even, since

$n = 2k \Longrightarrow n^2 = 4k^2 = 2(2k^2) \Longrightarrow 2 \mid n^2; \tag 2$

likewise, the square of an odd is odd:

$n = 2k + 1 \Longrightarrow n^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1; \tag 3$

it follows that $n + 1$ is even, and hence

$n = (n + 1) - 1 \tag 4$

is odd; this may more formally seen by writing

$n + 1 = 2k$
$\Longrightarrow n = 2k - 1 = (2k -2) + 1 = 2(k - 1) + 1, \; \text{odd}. \tag 5$

$OE\Delta$.

The contradiction in the above proof is rather subtly buried, and not explicitly mentioned; it occurs when we infer $n + 1$ is even from $(n + 1)^2$ is even; there we tacitly assume $n + 1$ is odd which, in light of (2) and (3), forces $(n + 1)^2$ odd, contradicting the demonstrated even-ness of $(n + 1)^2$.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank your response. I think after reading your input i understand proof by contradiction a little.

Comment: @OrenciaParris:  glad to help out.  Upvotes/acceptance always appreciated.  Cheers!